# PAM deems Kerberos password as expired

Tags: ldap, kerberos, replication, pam

I run Kerberos / LDAP authentication in a small network for years. Kerberos is held in LDAP, which in turn is replicated to another site. Machines at the second site authenticate to the replica, the old site authenticates to the original server. Recently, I added a couple of new user accounts.

On the original site, everything runs smoothly. The new users can login to the system without any issue.

On the second site using the replica `kinit user` also works without problems. However, `login user` claims that the password has expired and shall be changed, immediately. After changing the password, the user is logged in nicely.

Checking the settings on the replica KDC with `kadmin.local` everything looks nice to me:

```
kadmin.local:  getprinc user
Principal: user@EXAMPLE.COM
Expiration date: [never]
Last password change: Di Nov 22 21:06:35 CET 2022
Password expiration date: [never]
Maximum ticket life: 0 days 10:00:00
Maximum renewable life: 7 days 00:00:00
Last modified: Di Nov 22 21:06:35 CET 2022 (kadmind@EXAMPLE.COM)
Last successful authentication: Di Nov 22 21:19:27 CET 2022
Last failed authentication: So Nov 13 09:05:17 CET 2022
Failed password attempts: 0
Number of keys: 8
[ ... ]
Attributes: REQUIRES_PRE_AUTH
Policy: [none]
```

So, neither passwords nor principals expire. And thus `kinit` works as expected:

```
root@client:~# kinit user
Password for user@EXAMPLE.COM: 
root@client:~# klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: user@EXAMPLE.COM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
22.11.2022 21:25:17  23.11.2022 07:25:17  krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM
        renew until 23.11.2022 21:25:11
```

However, `login` claims that the password is expired and must be changed:

```
root@ganesha:~# login user
Password: 
Sie müssen Ihr Passwort sofort ändern (Passwortablauf).
Current Kerberos password: 
Enter new Kerberos password: 
Retype new Kerberos password: 
Linux client 5.10.0-19-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.149-2 (2022-10-21) x86_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Letzte Anmeldung: Dienstag, den 22. November 2022, 20:59:02 CET auf pts/5
user@client:~$
```

Following this login the principal's `Last password change` and `Last modified` are updated. `Last successful authentication` does not change. It doesn't change after successful `kinit` either. But it does change for successful `login` or `kinit` on the original clients. This may be another issue, but it happens just the same with the old users, which work perfectly on both sites. Using `getprinc` I cannot spot any difference between the old and the new users.

For `login` the following PAM settings should be effective for `auth` and `account` i.e., the defaults of a Debian installation:

```
auth    optional   pam_faildelay.so  delay=3000000
auth    requisite  pam_nologin.so
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=1000
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
auth    required                        pam_permit.so
auth    optional   pam_group.so

account [success=1 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]        pam_unix.so 
account requisite                       pam_deny.so
account required                        pam_permit.so
account required                        pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=1000
```

I set up a new Bullseye client, which uses the original Kerberos and LDAP through VPN. It shows the same behaviour. I did some PAM debugging:

```
Jan 23 21:32:44 psyche login[2861]: pam_krb5(login:auth): user user authenticated as user@EXAMPLE.COM
Jan 23 21:32:44 psyche login[2861]: pam_unix(login:account): expired password for user user (password aged)
Jan 23 21:32:53 psyche login[2861]: pam_krb5(login:chauthtok): user user changed Kerberos password
Jan 23 21:32:53 psyche login[2861]: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user user(uid=10##) by admin(uid=0)
```

The old users, which work fine on all systems do not have an entry for `(login:account)` and hence no password change, of course. So, it doesn't seem to be related to replication. Even weirder that there are systems, where `login` works fine for those users. I checked `/etc/pam.d/common-account` and it is identical on both systems.

I appreciate any ideas on what to check.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What PAM auth (and account) modules are actually in use on this system?

Answer (score 0):

The actual reason was unrelated to Kerberos. The failing accounts had `shadowMax` set in LDAP. While I was unaware of this setting in the first place, credentials are reported as expired even if `shadowLastChange` plus `shadowMax` is still behind the current date. Setting `shadowMax` to -1 or deleting the value altogether fixes the issue.

This does not quite explain why the set-up at the other site apparently ignores the value entirely, but this is another story.